# display code.gs file being run by web app

Tags: google-apps-script

I write basic web apps for my personal use and am only one step above a noob. The current version of my web app runs a different code.gs file than the one that is saved, i.e., the code.gs file that comes up when I open the project from the apps script dashboard. I can't find the currently running file in the previous deployed versions in the Manage Deployments dialog. It seems to me that a version is running that is kind of inbetween deployments. Is there a way to display and edit the file that is currently in use by the web app? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To run the latest code you can create a new version.

On the new IDE you can't see the previous version code, on the old IDE if you go to `File` -> `See version history`.

But to run the script you have on the screen on the new IDE, you have to deploy a new version.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was able to find the REVISION I was looking for with the old IDE. Your answer taught me there are versions deployed and there are revisions to file(s).

Comment: Hi, If the answer was helpful please consider accepting it so more people can find it.

Comment: Hi. I did accept it. I was notified that since I have less than 15 posts, the acceptance would not be displayed.  Let me know if I should do something else. Thanks again.